# Projection texture painting, is it possible to swap images after applying brush?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, texture-painting

I'm trying to use the same uv mapping and brush texture painting with a few near identical human face photos.

Is that possible? I know with F clone you can just swap out a different image and use the same uv map as the source clone uv map, but that resets all of the brush work(sorry, meant you have to draw all over again with the brush, doesn't replace the original brush work with the new source clone image).

[image: So IMG is the original source clone image that was used to create the "front" uv mapping, i'm asking if it's possible to have the same brush style applied with a different source clone image, but same uv mapping, without having to redraw on top(so it would essentially replace the original source clone image texture exactly as it was drawn.]

So IMG is the original source clone image that was used to create the "front" uv mapping, i'm asking if it's possible to have the same brush work applied with a different source clone image, but same uv mapping, without having to redraw on top(so it would essentially replace the original source clone image texture exactly as it was drawn).

Comment: Can you include a few screen shots of what you mean here? If the target is being painted, the target should retain the pixels painted regardless of the source changing.

Comment: Sorry, I worded that incorrectly, I meant you have to redraw with the new source clone image, as opposed to it replacing the already existing texture. Elaborated in the original question as you suggested.

Comment: Still don't understand the question: are you asking if the new source image will replace the pixels already cloned into the target image from the previous source image?

Comment: Yes, exactly that! I'm asking if it's possible to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using 3 uv maps, on for front projection, one for side projection, and one for regular unwrap with seams to avoid stretch. Here each texture is set to a different slot, and a black image is set as stencil and intensity between them, and that one is painted with white to reveal the image below. In this case, you can then replace the texture use for the front view or the side view and the stencil will affect it the same way.[image]